# Counting and summing (and averaging) in an awk array

Tags: shell, awk, array

I have a data file that contains dates and corresponding measurements of some quantity. The full file stretches over 13 years and has ~4500 data points-- I have given an example of the format below. There is not necessarily a measurement on each day, i.e. some dates correspond to a blank value in the data column, titled "pbl".

I want to compute, for each year of my dataset, the number of observations (i.e. a count of non-zero values) and also the sum. Then I'll repeat this, but for each month. Sort-of cheating, I have added columns with the full dates reduced to "year" and "month-year" to make this easier.

I am using awk and can sum correctly. The problem is counting. Currently my line of awk counts the number of days per year (or per month) and *not* the number of observations. So, for the full dataset, I get "365" or "366" i.e. the total number of entries listed in the date column; what I want to get is the number of these dates that have a corresponding measurement in the "pbl" column.

My hunch is that I need to include a "for non-zero term" clause somewhere or count on $4 instead of $2, but I can't work out how to do this. Any tips appreciated!

My code:

`awk -F, '{a[$2]++; count[$2]+=$NF}END{for (i in a) print i,a[i],count[i]}' data.csv`

My data (sample):

> "date","year","month-year","pbl"
>
> 05/12/04,2004,"12-2004",960.295
>
> 06/12/04,2004,"12-2004",
>
> 13/12/04,2004,"12-2004",911.774
>
> 29/12/04,2004,"12-2004",2804.06
>
> 30/12/04,2004,"12-2004",4453.56
>
> 01/01/05,2005,"01-2005",1326.38
>
> 07/01/05,2005,"01-2005",
>
> 08/01/05,2005,"01-2005",604.919
>
> 09/01/05,2005,"01-2005",755.006
>
> 10/01/05,2005,"01-2005",
>
> 11/01/05,2005,"01-2005",978.818
>
> 12/01/05,2005,"01-2005",
>
> 13/01/05,2005,"01-2005",1644.87
>
> 29/04/05,2005,"04-2005",3630.62
>
> 30/04/05,2005,"04-2005",3780.11
>
> 01/05/05,2005,"05-2005",1262.66
>
> 02/05/05,2005,"05-2005",
>
> 14/02/06,2006,"02-2006",5667.58
>
> 15/02/06,2006,"02-2006",2696.56
>
> 23/07/07,2007,"07-2007",1276.06
>
> 24/07/07,2007,"07-2007",

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to process only those lines with a value in `$4`:

```
awk -F, '$4 {a[$2]++; count[$2]+=$NF}END{for (i in a) print i,a[i],count[i]}' data.csv
```

This works because

```
$4 {a[$2]++; count[$2]+=$NF}
```

causes the block to only be executed on lines where `$4` evaluates to true, *i.e.* where `$4` is non-empty and non-zero.

Comment: Cool! I didn't know about this trick-- can you explain a little more why it works? Could two columns be specified in front like this? What's the syntax in that case?

Comment: I added an explanation to the answer. You could specify two columns by writing `$2 && $4` for example for columns two and four.

Comment: One further query, if I may: this is currently summing the final column ($4): if there were multiple columns of data, e.g. $5 and $6 as well, how do I modify the command to count those instead? To put it another way, is there a way to modify the current line of awk that forces it to count and sum for a chosen column, not just the final one?

Comment: Use the field number instead of `NF`: `count[$2]+=$4` etc. (And you can use multiple arrays to sum different columns separately.)

Comment: Ah, ok. Thus...
`awk -F, '$5 {a[$3]++; b[$3]+=$5; c[$3]+=$6; d[$3]+=$7}END{for (i in a) print i,a[i],b[i],c[i],d[i]}' data.csv | sort`

Thanks!